# TabLayout inside fragment give wrong items view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am working in project that I use Tablayout inside fragment , I have three tabs where they fetch data from web service , this part of the app show questions , we have three categories one for recent , second for un answered third for all question view

here is my situation my web developer design me web service return question item , they all share the same structure in returned item but data changed according to requirement .

```
public class Questions_Fragment extends Fragment  {

    private TabLayout mTablayout;
    private ViewPager mViewpager;

    public static Questions_Fragment newInstance() {
        Questions_Fragment fragment = new Questions_Fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questions_layout, null);
        mViewpager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setupViewPager(mViewpager);

        mTablayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);

        return v;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager mViewpager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag( QuestionsFragModel.newInstance(VolleyRequestHandler.RECENT_INT) , getResources().getString(R.string.newest));
        adapter.addFrag( QuestionsFragModel.newInstance(VolleyRequestHandler.UNANSWER_INT) , getResources().getString(R.string.notanswered));
        adapter.addFrag( QuestionsFragModel.newInstance(VolleyRequestHandler.ALLPOSTS_INT) , getResources().getString(R.string.allposts));
        mViewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

my view pager adapter class I extend  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` data could change each time user open tab

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList=  new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fra , String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fra);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

but I see it give me wrong view, it show image in question dont have image and it give answer to unanswered question

sorry for my long question but I want know what is wrong with my code ??

my list adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context _Context;

    private List<QuestionItem> Questions = new ArrayList<>();
    private API api;
    private int num;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    public static final String BASE_POST_URl = "url....";


    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionItem> Questions) {
        this._Context = context;
        this.Questions = Questions;
        api = new API(context);
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionItem> Questions,
                           int num) {
        this._Context = context;
        this.Questions = Questions;
        this.num = num;
        api = new API(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_Context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_Context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/GE_SS_Two_Bold.otf");
        Typeface tfreg = Typeface.createFromAsset(_Context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/GE_SS_Two_Light.otf");

        ImageLoader _ImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(_Context).getmImageLoader();

        if (Questions.get(position).user.userimageURL != null) {
            if (!Questions.get(position).user.getUserimageURL().isEmpty()) {
                //holder.userimageprog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageView.setImageUrl(Profile_Fragment.BASE_URL + Questions.get(position).user.getUserimageURL(), _ImageLoader);
            }
        }

        if(Questions.get(position).Que_image_url != null){
            if (!Questions.get(position).getQue_image_url().isEmpty()) {
                holder._FrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.post_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //holder.post_img_pro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.post_img.setImageUrl(BASE_POST_URl + Questions.get(position).getQue_image_url(), _ImageLoader);
            }
        }

        holder.imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.profile);
        holder.username.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.desc.setTypeface(tfreg);
        holder.Date.setTypeface(tfreg);
        holder.AnswersCount.setTypeface(tfreg);

        if(Questions.get(position).user.username != null){
            holder.username.setText(Questions.get(position).user.username);
        }
        if(Questions.get(position).Que_Content != null){
            holder.desc.setText(Questions.get(position).Que_Content);
        }
        if(Questions.get(position).category != null){
            holder.Category.setText(Questions.get(position).category);
        }

        if(Questions.get(position).Que_Date != null){
            holder.Date.setText(Questions.get(position).Que_Date);
        }

        if (!Questions.get(position).getComment().isEmpty()) {
            holder.arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.AnswersCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.AnswersCount.setText(_Context.getResources().getString(R.string.youhaveanswer));
        }
        holder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (_Context , ViewAnswers.class);
                intent.putExtra("passedobject", (Parcelable) Questions.get(position));
                _Context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


//      Animation animation = null;
//       animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_Context,
//                 R.anim.up_from_bottom);
//       animation.setDuration(500);
//          view.setAnimation(animation);
//            animation = null;
//
//      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_Context,
//              (pos > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
//                      : R.anim.down_from_top);
//      view.startAnimation(animation);
//      lastPosition = pos;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Questions.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected NetworkImageView imageView, post_img;
        protected TextView desc, Category, username, Date, AnswersCount;
        protected ProgressBar userimageprog, post_img_pro;
        protected ImageView arrow;
        protected FrameLayout _FrameLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques_user_img);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ques_content);
            Category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            post_img = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_img);
            userimageprog = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userimgae_prog);
            post_img_pro = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_prog);
            username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_ques);
            Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            AnswersCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answers_con);
            arrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            _FrameLayout = (FrameLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);

        }
    }
}
```

QuestionsFragModel view

```
public class QuestionsFragModel extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView Ques_list;
    private ProgressBar list_prog;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<QuestionItem> Questions = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView reload;
    private VolleyRequestHandler _VolleyRequestHandler;
    private int CONST_TYPE = 0;
    public static final String PASSED_INT = "passed_number";
    private CoordinatorLayout _coordiatelayout;


    static QuestionsFragModel newInstance(int type) {
        QuestionsFragModel f = new QuestionsFragModel();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(PASSED_INT , type);
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_layout, container, false);
        CONST_TYPE = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(PASSED_INT) : 7;
        _VolleyRequestHandler = new VolleyRequestHandler(getActivity());
        _coordiatelayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.coordiatelayout);

        Ques_list = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.questionlist);
        Ques_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), Questions);
        Ques_list.setAdapter(adapter);


        list_prog = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        reload = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reload);

        getQuestationsPosts();

        reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View position) {
                getQuestationsPosts();
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionButton floatingView = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.FloatingView);
        if (floatingView != null) {
            floatingView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void getQuestationsPosts() {
        API api = new API(getActivity());
        if (api.isNetworkConnected()) {
            list_prog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            FetchQuestationsFromWeb();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(_coordiatelayout, getResources().getString(R.string.nointernet), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Ques_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    private void onSuccessResponse(Object response){
        list_prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        reload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Ques_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(Questions != null){
            Questions.clear();
        }
        Questions = (List < QuestionItem>)  response;
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity() ,Questions);
        Ques_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void onErrorResponse(String error){
        list_prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        reload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Snackbar.make(_coordiatelayout , error , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void FetchQuestationsFromWeb() {

        _VolleyRequestHandler.HandleRequests(Request.Method.POST , CONST_TYPE, null, new VolleyResponseCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void RequestSuccess(Object response) {
                onSuccessResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void RequestFailed(String error) {
                onErrorResponse(error);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Add_Question.class));
    }


}
```

Comment: Who gives you the wrong view, the ViewPagerAdapter?. Can you post your QuestionsFragModel.class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` when you have only 3 fragments.

AFAIK, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is better for performance if you have a large amount of fragments, because it don't stores the whole fragment in memory.

Anyway, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will save out your fragment's Bundle from savedInstanceState when it is destroyed. And when the user navigates back, the new fragment will be restored using the fragment's state.

So you need to check `savedInstanceState` before:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_layout, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            // restore your state from "savedInstanceState"
        } else{
            CONST_TYPE = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(PASSED_INT) : 7;
        }
}
```

Comment: I fetch data from web each time user open fragment ? it still give wrong view , it load images in places shouldnt appear

Comment: First, try to debug your code and make sure your fragment have always the right CONST_TYPE (when it first created and when you navigate back to it).

Comment: I change to FragmentPagerAdapter and I notice savedInstanceState always return null

Answer (score 1):

If someone face some issue, it cause of I use if statement in adapter , simply you can use if only without else

Example I use if only

```
if (Questions.get(position).user.userimageURL != null) {
    if (!Questions.get(position).user.getUserimageURL().isEmpty()) {
        //holder.userimageprog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(Profile_Fragment.BASE_URL + Questions.get(position).user.getUserimageURL(), _ImageLoader);
    }
} else{
    // I should use else statement as well                  
}
```